# SQL: select Sub query opposite to its parent query's where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
invoice_payments

invoice_id amount type
         1  10.00 Cash
         1   5.00 Cash
         1   5.00 Cash
         2  70.00 Store
         2  30.00 Cash
```

I want to get rows with total amounts with cash and total amounts with type = store

I am using this query:

```
SELECT invoice_id, SUM( amount ) AS total_paid, (
SELECT SUM( amount )  FROM invoice_payments WHERE TYPE =  'store' ) AS total_store
FROM invoice_payments  where type!='Store'
GROUP BY invoice_id
```

Result:

```
invoice_id total_paid total_store
         1      20.00       70.00
         2     100.00       70.00
```

Desired Result:

```
invoice_id total_paid total_store
         1      20.00       0.00
         2     100.00       70.00
```

As you can see total_store field is not values correctly. Please suggest best solution.

I really appreciate any reply.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add on your question what should be the desired result?

Comment: I provided desired result. Please see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select `invoice_id`, (select sum(`amount`) from `payments` p where p.invoice_id = a.invoice_id) 'total_paid', (select sum(`amount`) from `payments` c where c.invoice_id = a.invoice_id and type = 'store') 'total_store' from `payments` a group by `invoice_id`

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using a case statement here instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT
    invoice_id,
    Sum(amount) as total_paid,      
    Sum(CASE WHEN type='store' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as Store_Total        
FROM
    invoice_payments
GROUP BY invoice_id
```

Comment: Yes but I need  where type!='Store' in the parent query, so in that way it will not work.

Comment: I just added not_in_store_total. Feel free to add or remove fields as needed. Writing CASE statements is not difficult.

Comment: I don't need Not_in_store_total

Comment: Check this I need where type!='Store'  at the end 
`SELECT
    invoice_id,
    Sum(amount) as total,
    Sum(CASE WHEN type='cash' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as Cash_total,
    Sum(CASE WHEN type='store' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as Store_Total
    
FROM
    invoice_payments where type!='Store'  
GROUP BY invoice_id`

Comment: Hi @Maria if you put this condition on your query: `type!='Store'` then this case statement `Sum(CASE WHEN type='store' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)` will be useless because your query will never sum a value that is a 'Store'. I understand qhat you want and the case statement provided already do this condition for you, because it is summing only the other type which is 'cash'

Comment: I understand, But I edited my question and I added "Desired Result" 
Look at that and you will know How I want to display record.

Comment: Perhaps remove the `Sum(amount) as total,` and the `Sum(CASE WHEN type<>'store' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as Not_in_store_total` from the query above and that will be what you need. You will have the `invoice_id`, the `amount` where the `type` is JUST `cash` and the amount where the `type` is just `store`.

Comment: I have edited my answer to fit your 'desired results'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.invoice_id
     , SUM(x.amount) total_paid
     , SUM(CASE WHEN x.type = 'store' THEN x.amount ELSE 0 END) total_store 
  FROM invoice_payments x 
 GROUP 
    BY x.invoice_id;
```

Comment: But I need to keep  where type!='Store' condition on the parent query as well. So in that way it will not work.

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a different question, or edit the existing one - because right now you're not making much sense.

Comment: @Maria once more, you are not making much sense because your affirmative about `I need to keep where type!='Store'` does not make any sense based on the cenario you gave. Pehaps if you change your question with a situation that explain why you need this constraint would help everyone to give you a proper answer.